# Java.awt.polygon in android

Tags: java, android

Is there a way that I can use the java.awt.Polygon class in my android app? I have tried importing at the top but I still cannot use Polygon.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download [the source code to a version of `java.awt.Polygon`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/harmony/enhanced/archive/classlib/java6/modules/awt/src/main/java/common/java/awt/Polygon.java), refactor it into `jonny.Polygon` (or whatever), and use it in accordance to the source code license.

This will probably require doing the same thing for many other classes as well (that `Polygon` depends upon), and eventually you may run into something that you cannot readily convert this way.

Hence, I would recommend that you find some other solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve.